# Issue with Bootstrap 4 Modals and Angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm running into some issues with Bootstrap 4.3.1 Modals and Angular 8, I already checked many cases that had the same issue but none of them worked.

**What I've done :**

So I literally copy/pasted the following code from **Bootstrap** official page (Live Demo one): [Copied code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

And it's not working and not rendering any errors in console or browser, here's my **HTML**:

```
<button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-primary"></button>


<div class="modal fade in" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone had the same issue ?

**EDIT :**

Issue resolved following those steps : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232092/bootstrap-4-0-modal-not-working-with-angular-4/48232476)

Thank's for your time and your help

Comment: Have u installed jquery?

Comment: what is the error in console ?

Comment: Yes, via `npm install jquery --save`

Comment: @GaneshGudghe there's none

Comment: check please:
https://therichpost.com/angular-8-bootstrap-popup-login-form/

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed incorrectly:

1. `npm install bootstrap`
   `npm install jquery — save`
2. Config **angular.json**

> ```
> ...
> "styles": [
>   "src/styles.css",
>   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
> ],
> "scripts": [
>   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
> ]
> ...
> ```

3.Import directly in src/style.css or src/style.scss:

`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: It doesn't work, boostrap style works but there's an issue only with Modals