# Bootstrap modal does not pop up in Angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular8, angular-bootstrap

I've worked with modals before and never had such an issue. My bootstrap modal does not pop up. However, it is shown in the bottom of the page, while I want it to pop up just like a modal should do.

My html:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
 </ng-template>
```

My .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
}
```

and Imports in app.module contain NgbModule of course

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
```

This is my package.json (sorry it's not formatted as code, stackoverflow does not allow me to paste so much code):

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-path ../expenses/wwwroot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.13",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any error in the console? If you use Scss, are you sure you included the modals scss file in your build?

Comment: No errors, and no, I don't use scss, I use css

Comment: Are you sure NgbModal is the actual modal service?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244566/ngbmodal-open-not-working-in-angular-4)? Seems like bootstrap versions are not compatible.

Comment: Try to copy & paste the [ng-bootstrap Modal example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), see if it works, then change it to fit your needs. Angular is a rather complicated framework so it's hard to pinpoint the exact problem at times.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Probably has something to do with not compatible versions, but cannot find any info about that. I'm using Angular 8 and bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after many hours of looking for a solution I found out that yes, Bootstrap version was incompatible with Angular version. I had to use ngx-bootstrap library which worked like a charm. Huge thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232092/bootstrap-4-0-modal-not-working-with-angular-4/48232476) which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your app module import section add

```
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

instead of just NgbModule.
Also Make sure that ng-bootstrap version is compatible with angular version.

Comment: I tried it, but Angular shows an error when adding .forRoot. Don't remember which one, can't check the code rn. Will update later.

Comment: It simply states that "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'"